# ec2 coppied AMI carries over old.ppk key, need to change keys

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

i copied a private AMI (lamp) over from a different account and created a new instance on ec2. the new instance has a new.pem key associated with it and i can see the title from AWS Management Console: Key Pair Name.

I've created a **new.ppk** file from **new.pem**. However when i log in SSH the new key does not work and the **old.ppk** key still seems to work.
how can i fix this?
would like to get rid of the old key and set **new.ppk** to be valid

should i follow this?
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46776&tstart=45#179656

saw this article 
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233
but found it confusing, it talks about logging in as root while also saying to disable root login

Comment: found this and helped out!!! http://serverfault.com/questions/310926/cant-change-assigned-key-pair-on-amazon-ec2-instance

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the old key from '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' and paste in the new public key. Make sure the new key is in OpenSSH format and all on one line.

Comment: yes,  what messed me up was that it seems to need 2 entries ... maybe its just my instance thats weird