# Accessing RDS or EC2 instance without '.pem' key

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds, scp

I am working for a charity who has a few of their services on AWS.

They hired an agency years ago to spin up these intranet and tools platforms. I am trying to get a dump of their db, for backup archiving, and extracting some content before terminating these platforms. I have the following two ways to try and get the db:

1. Access the RDS and dump it to my local machine
2. Access the EC2 instance, do a postgres dump and scp the file

I have not had much luck with no 1. However using the AWS console (web interface in a browser) I managed to connect to the instance and save the dump to /tmp

Can someone please help me with either getting no 1 working, or no 2 assist me with ssh/scp from command line, as I do not have the .pem file available for scp access.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use point-in-time restore to make a copy of the RDS instance, with a new password and security group rules that allow you to `pg_dump` against it.

Comment: If you have console access you can scp the file out to a different box. That's probably the easiest way out.

Comment: If you have the dump made, the simplest option may be to upload the dump to an S3 bucket, then download it from there to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: @vidarlo how can I scp from aws console to my local machine as I don't have the .pem for it via bash

Comment: @Tim how can I go from EC2 to S3? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change assigned key pair on amazon ec2 instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/310926/cant-change-assigned-key-pair-on-amazon-ec2-instance)

Comment: To get data from EC2 to S3 you would typically use the AWS CLI v2. "aws s3 cp" is the basic command, from there search will find the details for you. Make sure you set your S3 bucket to private.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is in RDS and you don't need up to the minute data, you should be able to create a RDS snapshot. Then use that snapshot to restore the database to a new RDS instance.

On that new RDS instance you should be able to change the security group information along with the [master db password](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds). Though I've never done it with PostgreSQL. I can't remember if RDS uses a key or not, but you can generally assign a new one when you restore from a snapshot. Go through the process slowly and expand all of the options because it may not be obvious where to do this.

I recommend doing this with a new RDS instance (restored from the snapshot) because you won't impact the running system and you are free to make more drastic changes.

Once you have that new RDS instance and you can connect to it, you have a few options. You can try to directly connect and dump data, you can try to [export the data from RDS to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) or you can spin up EC2 instance that you fully control and do it via that system.

Once you've got the data out, don't forget to clean up the RDS instance (and snapshot) you created. Remember stopping an RDS instance only lasts for 7 days before it will turn itself on and incur usage charges.